# Редирект Node JS (post запрос)

Tags: node.js, редирект

Не понимаю почему не работает редирект в случае statusCode = 200
Точнее я предполагаю что переменная пуста, но въехать почему так и не смог. 
прошу помощи разобраться в решении проблемы, быть может какое то альтернативное решение имеется.
ПС. В JS и в node очень слаб.

Суть проблемы в том что нужно после обработки полученных данных, где формируется ссылка на новую страницу, перенаправить пользователя на неё в случае успешного insert в коллекцию.

На странице есть форма без action, скриптом беру все данные с формы и отправляю их на обработку

```
    $(document.forms['create']).on('submit',function(){     
    var form = $(this);
    $("body").prepend('');
    $("submit", form).button('loading');

    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_AJAX + "create/",
        method: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        complete: function() {
            $("submit", form).button("reset");
        },
        statusCode: {
            200: function(jqXHR) {
                var url = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText); // пытаюсь получить ссылку на пост
                window.location.href = url.message;
            },
            403: function(jqXHR) {
                var error = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                $("body").prepend('<div class="msg-error closed">' + error.message + '</div>');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

В самом обработчике в случае возникновения проблем пишу торможу выполнение и вывожу ошибку

```
    ........ <<<< обработка данных
    ], function (err, obj) {
        if(err) return next(new HttpError(403, err)); // в случае ошибки

        // Если все в порядке то ниже уже пробовал много вариантов и что то не получилось ничего
            // Делал даже так
            next(new HttpError(200, obj.url)); // ссылка на новость, так не помогло, ничего не происходит

    });
```

Далее попробовал сделать редирект отдав статус 403 и прописав в statusCode 403

```
window.location.href = url.message;
```

В обработчике

```
next(new HttpError(403, obj.url)); // Так работает
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: почему просто в ответ не положить obj.url ? зачем new HttpError(200, obj.url) ? Вообще ткните в доку где вообще так задается error.

Comment: Обычно так:

[код ошибки](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode)

[послать ответ и закончить](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding)

Comment: @alvoro да где вообще этот HttpError используется ? есть [какая-то либа](https://www.npmjs.org/package/httperror) но она вообще не про то.

Comment: @eicto У меня такое чувство, что это [отсюда][1]

[1]: https://github.com/iliakan/nodejs-screencast/blob/master/chat/13/error/index.js

Comment: eicto, ну я ж нубас, я не понимаю как правильно это делать =)
alvoro, да из скинкаста брал функцию обработки ошибок (Учусь еще)
В консоле пишет
method: POST
status: 200
type: application/json
Вроде все норм.
а нет еще заметил что ошибку выдает
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
На этой линии var url = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);

Я так думаю что ошибка вызвана тем что jqXHR пустая

Comment: @webphp Это не ошибка выполнения. Вы где-то или скобку левую поставили, или переменную не определили. Проверьте код и исправьте ее.

Comment: [Публичное самоунижение не заменяет выполнение домашних заданий](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#grovelling)

вы если хотите починить что-то, то на вопросы отвечайте. например - где вы вообще взяли этот HttpError ? 

если действительно из скринкастов - бросайте это дело, в смысле **не учатся программированию через видеоуроки**

Comment: @alvoro у меня такое чувство, что эти уроки из разряда "как программировать на js так-же как на php" по крайней мере по этому кусочку видно. зачем это делать вообще не понятно. я ещё понимаю, express там что-то облегчает а тут... все только запутывает.

---

неправильная практика вредна.

@webphp а зачем вы делаете application/json, когда присылаете не json ? поэтому и не парсится json.

Comment: @eicto Позволю себе с вами не согласится. Имхо, любой процесс обучения заключается в получении информации, обработки ее своим мозгом и попытке применить на практике. А путь, каким эта информация, попадает в мозг вряд ли имеет решающие значение. Практика важнее.

@eicto Комменты закончились(( Буду писать сюда. Тут я тоже с вами не согласен. Если та часть скринкаста, которая посвящена созданию чата, и хромает, то первая, теоретическая, опять-таки имхо, просто обязательна для просмотра и пересмотра начинающими.

Comment: Ребят я конечно понимаю что вы опытные программисты на JS, но к новичкам то можно и по спокойней относиться =)
Я уже написал что взял функцию из скринкаста.
Почему нельзя учится на скринкастах? 
Я не вижу особой проблемы в том что можно посмотреть как пишут код, а опыт, он приходит со временем, так что для старта уроки по скринкасту самое оно. По крайней мере для меня.

Comment: не пойму где поправить, я так понял обработчик категорически отказывается передавать данные со статусом 200, с другим статусом 403 все работает. Возможно косяк в самом HttpError в случае отправки статуса 200, но там никаких условий на этот случай не написано вроде бы.

Только что получилось, отдал в обработчике
res.statusCode = 200;
res.write(url);
res.end();

Редирект сработал.

Спасибо люди добрые за подмогу =)

Comment: > res.statusCode = 200; res.write(url); res.end();

можно и так `res.statusCode = 200; res.end(url);`. А ошибку на клиенте все равно устраните. Потом может боком вылезти. Всегда пожалуйста

Comment: Сейчас ошибок нет, все в порядке, все исправил.